# How to make list items be on one row each

Tags: html, css, list

I am working on a website for my digit class and I am struggling to fix the left navigation bar. It is a list of Grimm Brothers fairytale title, but certain ones split into two or more lines. How can I make each title be on an individual line?  I have linked the site and my github repository css page. The ol is the title list and the ul is my navigation bar.

https://stf5123.github.io/Grimm_project/works2.html
https://github.com/STF5123/Grimm_project/blob/main/docs/webstyle.css

Comment: Removing `float: left;` and adding `white-space: nowrap;` to `ol li` will do the trick.

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question, not on other sites please. See [ask]